# AWS SAM - Config TOML File

Tags: aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

Working through a deployment on a stack using AWS SAM and deploying via GitHub actions and was trying to use the Config TOML file and specifying a config environment in the deploy command and I am running into the issue where it seems to be just ignoring what I am specifying in the deployment command.  Only thing I can only guess I am doing wrong is that I cannot actually use these or that I have it in the wrong location but I would greatly appreciate any help on the matter.  Not finding much out there in terms of similar examples or documentation.

```
sam deploy --stack-name mySuperAwesomeStuff \
--region ${{ secrets.AWS_REGION }} \
--confirm-changeset \
--config-file ./functions/function1/function1.toml \
--config-env nonprod \
--template-file ./functions/function1/template.yaml
```

Ideally I would love to get the region out of there and into the TOML file as well as the stackname.

My TOML file looks like this:

```
[nonprod.deploy.parameters]
stack_name="super-awesome-stack-name"
region="us-east-2"
confirm_changeset=true
cababilities="CABILITIES_IAM"
```

Once again, just seems to be completely ignoring me trying to use the config-file and I am not sure what I am missing here.

Answer (score 5):

i am new to sam cli myself and came across this issue and figured it out about 2minutes ago. it's a bit confusing at first, but you should know that the samconfig.toml file is being read when doing `sam deploy`, the key thing you're missing is the `environment` that you want to deploy. in your case, you have named it `nonprod`([nonprod.deploy.parameters] based on this line). the command you should be running for deployment should now be `sam deploy --stack-name super-awesome-stack-name --config-env nonprod`.

Comment: Yah that is what I have above.

--config-file ./functions/function1/function1.toml \
--config-env nonprod \

Answer (score 1):

My `samconfig.toml` also has a version at the top, like

```
version = 0.1
[nonprod.deploy.parameters]
region = "us-east-2"
```

I suspect this is the problem with `--config-file` attribute. I would suggest to rename the config to `samconfig.toml` and place it on the root, where you are running `sam deploy` to pinpoint the problem with `--config-file`.

Also, I found this which says that, `--config-file` is not implemented yet

https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/blob/develop/designs/sam-config.md#not-implemented

PS: I have my `samconfig.toml` on the root where I run `sam deploy` and it works like a charm.

Comment: Do not place the config file at the root, place it in the same folder as your sam template(s). That resolved my problem

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was specifying the **full path** to the samconfig.toml (instead of the relative path)

```
sam deploy --config-file <ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_CONFIG_FILE> --template-file <RELATIVE_OR_ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_TEMPLATE_FILE>
```

And my config file (samconfig.toml)

```
version = 0.1
[default.deploy.parameters]
stack_name = "xxx"
s3_bucket = "xxx"
s3_prefix = "xxx"
region = "xxx"
confirm_changeset = false
capabilities = "CAPABILITY_IAM"
image_repositories = []
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have added this header **[nonprod.deploy]** and then the parameters

```
[nonprod.deploy]
[nonprod.deploy.parameters]
stack_name="super-awesome-stack-name"
region="us-east-2"
confirm_changeset=true
cababilities="CABILITIES_IAM"
```